# How can I clean grease from a carpet?

Tags: cleaning, staining, carpet

Accidentally put a greasy material on my carpet. I tried to give it a dry clean, but no luck. What else could I do to remove that greasy stain?

Comment: You'd want to test to make sure it doesn't stain the carpet, but I'd suggest a degreaser + steam vacuum.

Comment: Knowing what the greasy substance is would also be helpful.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk. it is used mobil oil

Comment: Ouch. Motor oil is a tough one. The best detergent I know to use on it, it actually both expensive and kind of harsh (10% Alconox in 50:50 ethanol, distilled water). Have you tried something like Dawn dishsoap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - don't scrub it.  Scrubbing with improper treatment will work the stain further in.  Good news is that oil doesn't dry, so you can get it out. Bad news is that whatever filth is in the oil may set.

(I was curious what regular people do, so this is from Good Housekeeping)

1) Apply an absorbing agent. Baking soda is a good go-to and is relatively cheap. Apply liberally and let sit for 10 minutes. Vacuum it up.

2) Use 1 tbsp vinegar + 1 tbsp hand dishwashing detergent + 2 cups warm water. Sponge the stain and blot till absorbed, repeat as necessary.

3) Sponge with cold water and blot dry to absorb vinegar solution.

---

However, I have doubts as to the effectiveness of using any solution of mostly water on carpeted oil or grease.  What I would do, and know works, is use odorless mineral spirits to get the stain out.  Any kind of paint thinner will do, but OMS (as the name implies) doesn't have the same smell as others. Whatever OMS is not removed by blotting will quickly evaporate, along with the smell.

If you go the effective OMS route - follow the safety guidelines.  It's flammable until it evaporates.

Answer (score 1):

White vinegar is considered a simple solution to grease stains. Some vinegar, dishwater detergent, water, and glycerine together can help remove the stain. Start with some water by sponging the stain, then apply the other liquids via an absorbent pad.

Dab at the stain and allow the pad to absorb the grease over time, swapping out the pad when it gets too dirty. If done right, the stain should despair and you can rinse the area with cold water followed by a paper towel drying.